# Singleton value still zeroes

Tags: xcode, gps, singleton

I'm trying to use the singleton concept to retain GPS information, but I do no see where is the problem my variable display just zeroes.

Singleton.h:

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject

@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyA;
@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyB;
@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyC;

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance;

@end
```

Singleton.m:

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@interface Singleton ()
{
    NSString *variableA;
    NSString *variableB;
    NSString *variableC;
}
@end

@implementation Singleton

static Singleton *sharedInstance = nil;

+ (Singleton *)sharedInstance
{
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        variableA = nil;
        variableB = nil;
        variableC = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

in OverlayViewController.m:

```
#import "Singleton.h"

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
        NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
        CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

        if (currentLocation != nil) {
            _longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        }

        // Setting properties
        NSString *variableA = _latitudeLabel.text;
        [[Singleton sharedInstance] setPropertyA:variableA];      
}
```

Then I recall the value a bit further down ...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     NSString *variableA = [[Singleton sharedInstance] propertyA];    
     NSLog(@"Latitude = %.8f", variableA);
}
```

Thanks Regis

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you don't have any @synthesize anywhere, so there are no setter/getters

If that doesn't work, then you should move your variable declarations to your .h file, I don't see why you would have them on your .m anyways

I refer to this:

```
@interface Singleton ()
{
    NSString *variableA;
    NSString *variableB;
    NSString *variableC;
}
@end
```

**Edit:** 
Two good practices when dealing with singletons:

1) Declare your `static ClassName *singleton` inside your method, so that other methods in your class don't have direct access to it and need to request it with `[[self class] sharedInstance];`

2) Use dispatch_once for thread safety

```
+ (FooBar *)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static FooBar *_sharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });

    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Xcode 4.4 and newer autosynthesizes accessors for properties.

Answer (score 0):

`@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyA;`
`@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyB;`
`@property (readwrite) NSString *propertyC;`

I guess above variables are not having setters and getters,  mean you would be require to @synthesize them.

Thats why the below code not setting the PropertyA value.

`[[Singleton sharedInstance] setPropertyA:variableA];`

Comment: Sorry, guys, I'm really trying but I cannot pin point the problem. Can you guide me to a small Xcode tutorial with it's associated source code that show how to set and get the singleton values? many thanks Regis